# Why this code for removing nodes from linked list doesn't work?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am working on a question on Leetcode, which aims to remove linked list elements.

Here's the question:

> 203. Remove Linked List Elements
>
> Example
>
> Given: 1 --> 2 --> 6 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6, val = 6
>
> Return: 1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5

And here's my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
ListNode* removeElements(ListNode* head, int val) {
    ListNode* cur = head;
    while(cur -> next != NULL && cur -> next -> val != val)
    {
        cur = cur -> next;
    }
    
    cur -> val = cur -> next -> val;
    cur -> next = cur -> next -> next;
    
    return head;
   }
};
```

I bumped into a runtime error when I submitted the code. The question is really simple, but since I am not so familiar with C++, I still can't find out where the error is. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You don't catch 'element not found' error, so I guess it's your runtime problem

Comment: Your code doesn't handle empty lists.

Comment: Just play it through, even on paper if necessary. If the value happens to be in the last position, then where does `cur->next->next` point to?

Comment: `cur -> val = cur -> next -> val;`  you don't need to do this. you just need to move `next` pointer to `next next` element

Comment: What if the node to delete is the first node?  Does your code handle that case correctly?

Comment: Make your title better and remove the "tag" from it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code crashes because the loop has two exit conditions:

- You found the node that you were looking for, and
- You reached the end of the list without finding the node

Your code assumes it's the first, not second condition, so it dereferences cur->next->val which may lead to a crash.

There are other problems with your code:

- You need to handle deletion of multiple items, as shown in the example
- You need to prevent memory leaks by freeing deleted nodes
- You need to process a situation when head points to the node that must be deleted
- You need to process a situation when the list is empty.